# Parsing <geo:lat>, <geo:long> tags value using feedparser in python!

Tags: python, feedparser

I am using feedparser for parsing from XML file.But I couldn't parse `<geo:lat>`, `<geo:long>` tags using feedparser from that file! Do you people have any idea how I can parse those tags using feedparser in python?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feedparser should parse [Basic Geo](http://www.feedparser.org/docs/namespace-handling.html) namespace with extension name **geo** without problem.
Check that your XML has http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos# namespace declaration like:

```
xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#"
```

This snippet should work:

```
 import feedparser
 d = feedparser.parse('http://yourfeed.xml')
 print d.entries[0].['geo_lat']
 print d.entries[0].['geo_long']
```

Comment: Yes! In my xml file it has namespace geo:lat and geo:long diclaration! But How to parse then? for example :<geo:lat>60.187953</geo:lat>
 <geo:long>24.803031</geo:long> , this is one item in my xml file! Do you mean any other speciafication as well?

Comment: Yes mine xml file has the same declaration as you told! But I couldn't get the parsed lat and long from this file! Could you please give me hints of code sample that I can get it?

Comment: I have tried but they showed error that:
AttributeError: object has no attribute 'geo_lat'

so perhaps geo_lat attribute not found! What else then?

Comment: @systempuntoout: Mine parse argument is just web URL , not just .xml file!so what I can do with this? do you have idea?

Comment: Could you post the URL to the feed you are trying to parse?

Comment: Well as this URL is related to location so I can't give the exact! But the format is :
http://geofeed.elisalabs.fi/web/rss/Lrge432sG173Dc44561CDD

Hope you understand!

Comment: I have pasted there! But what now?

Comment: You have to save the link to pastebin :)..Anyway, i've updated the snippet.Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

`<rss version="2.0" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">`

working example:

`import feedparser`

```
for item in d['items']`  
    print item['geo_lat']
    print item['geo_long']
```